# mysql : loop over tables and alter table add index

Tags: mysql, iteration, alter-table

I have ~1000 tables that start with the same prefix : 
`table_prefix_{SOME_ID}`   (i can take the ids from another table)

what is the fast way to loop over ***all*** the tables in mysql and do :

```
   ALTER TABLE `table_prefix_{some_id}` ADD INDEX `fields` (`field`)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Forget looping. Just do this:

```
select concat( 'alter table ', a.table_name, ' add index `fields` (`field`);' )
from information_schema.tables a 
where a.table_name like 'table_prefix_%';
```

Then take the result set and run it as a SQL script.

BTW, you probably mean `create index index_name on table_name( column_name);`