# Execute MySQL query in multiple databases at once

Tags: mysql, database

I have many MySQL databases that have same tables with the same structure. I am looking for simple way how can I alter table structure in all of the databases at once ( in one query or using one tool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see this solution like of alter many tables in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565060/mysql-loop-over-tables-and-alter-table-add-index) :

```
select concat( 'alter table ', a.table_name, ' add index `fields` (`field`);' )
from information_schema.tables a 
where a.table_name like 'table_prefix_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

A QND way, but anyhow,

- make changes on main-db with prefered tool.
- copy successful sql-statement to web-script (php or similar) that executes the
  sql with loop on defined 'slave' dbs.

//regards